# Django Form: Drop-Down/Select Not Rendering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

My present problem is that I've a form, Command_Form which has two fields, host_id and current_commands. Current_commands should be a drop-down menu of choices from CHOICES. However it does not do that and instead when I load the page it remains as a text-field I can type in, not a drop down select menu.

The following shows the issue. [image]

Forms.py code

```py
from django import forms
from django.forms import ChoiceField, ModelForm, RadioSelect
from .models import command_node
from .models import beacon

CHOICES = [
    ('Sleep', "Sleep"),
    ('Open SSH_Tunnel', 'Open SSH_Tunnel'),
    ('Close SSH_Tunnel', 'Close SSH_Tunnel'),
    ('Open TCP_Tunnel', 'Open TCP_Tunnel'),
    ('Close TCP_Tunnel', 'Close TCP_Tunnel'),
    ('Open Dynamic', 'Open Dynamic'),
    ('Close Dynamic', 'Close Dynamic'),
    ('Task', 'Task'),
]


class Command_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = command_node
        fields = (
            'host_id',
            'current_commands'
        )
        
        host_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            required=True,
            queryset=beacon.objects.all(),
            widget=forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                },
            )
        )

        current_comamnds = forms.ChoiceField(
            required=True,
            choices=CHOICES
        )
```

Views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import beacon
from .models import command_node
from .forms import Command_Form
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def home(request):
    form = Command_Form()
    if request.method == "POST":
            form = Command_Form(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return render(request, 'home.html', {"form": form})

    return render(request, 'home.html', {"form": form},)
```

Relevent HTML section

```html
/br>
</br>
    <form action="" method=POST>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Models.py

```py
from tkinter import CASCADE
from turtle import update
from django.db import models

class beacon(models.Model):
    host_id = models.BigAutoField('Id', primary_key=True)
    hostname = models.CharField('Hostname', max_length=200)
    internalIp = models.CharField('Internal-IP', max_length=200)
    externalIp = models.CharField('External-IP', max_length=200)
    current_user = models.CharField('Current_User', max_length=200)
    os = models.CharField('OS', max_length=200)
    admin = models.CharField('Admin', max_length=200)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.hostname

class command_node(models.Model):
    host_id = models.ForeignKey(beacon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_commands = models.CharField('current_command', max_length=50, null=True)
    previous_commands = models.CharField('previous_commands', max_length=2000, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.host_id)
```

Comment: Share your `command_node` model, and models, forms as well as views whichever are classes must be written in `PascalCase` not `snake_case`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show `current_commands` in the same way as you shown `host_id` in forms.py

But, I'd recommend to directly set choices in `command_node` model in the following way:

With current code do following modifcations in models.py and forms.py.

Try below code:

models.py

```py
class beacon(models.Model):
    host_id = models.BigAutoField('Id', primary_key=True)
    hostname = models.CharField('Hostname', max_length=200)
    internalIp = models.CharField('Internal-IP', max_length=200)
    externalIp = models.CharField('External-IP', max_length=200)
    current_user = models.CharField('Current_User', max_length=200)
    os = models.CharField('OS', max_length=200)
    admin = models.CharField('Admin', max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hostname


CHOICES = [
    ('Sleep', "Sleep"),
    ('Open SSH_Tunnel', 'Open SSH_Tunnel'),
    ('Close SSH_Tunnel', 'Close SSH_Tunnel'),
    ('Open TCP_Tunnel', 'Open TCP_Tunnel'),
    ('Close TCP_Tunnel', 'Close TCP_Tunnel'),
    ('Open Dynamic', 'Open Dynamic'),
    ('Close Dynamic', 'Close Dynamic'),
    ('Task', 'Task'),
]

class command_node(models.Model):
    host_id = models.ForeignKey(beacon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_commands = models.CharField(
        choices=CHOICES, max_length=50, null=True)
    previous_commands = models.CharField(
        'previous_commands', max_length=2000, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.host_id)
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.forms import ChoiceField, ModelForm, RadioSelect, SelectMultiple
from .models import CHOICES, command_node
from .models import beacon


class Command_Form(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = command_node
        fields = (
            'host_id',
            'current_commands'
        )

        host_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            required=True,
            queryset=beacon.objects.all(),
            widget=forms.SelectMultiple(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                },
            )
        )
```

> `Note:` Models, Forms, Class based views in django must be written in `PascalCase` not `snake_case` as they are classes of python, it will  be better if you name the models as `CommandNode` and `Beacon` rather than <s>`command_node`</s> and <s>`beacon`</s> respectively. And `CommandNodeForm` not <s>`Command_Node`</s>.